# Simple test app with scroll, content and image views - has problems with device rotation and zoom

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

In Xcode 5.1 I have created a very simple single view app for iPhone and put [the source code at GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/ScrollContent):

[image: app screenshot]

I have disabled Autolayout and put the following views in each other: `scrollView -> contentView -> imageView` (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPP2j.png)):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

For the `contentView` and `imageView` I've disabled Autoresizing and set their frames to `{0, 0, 1000, 1000}` - both in the Storyboard and in the [viewDidLoad](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/ScrollContent/ScrollContent/ViewController.m) method.

I have enabled double tap and pinch gestures for zooming.

For double tap the image is zoomed at 100% or 50% width.

This works initially, but **after device rotation it breaks:**

**The zoom doesn't work properly and the image is offset** - you can't scroll to its top left corner:

[image: image screenshot]

Here is my very short code in [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/ScrollContent/ScrollContent/ViewController.m), please advice how to fix it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    _contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    float scale = _scrollView.frame.size.width / 1000;

    _scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scale;
    _scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2 * scale;
    _scrollView.zoomScale = 2 * scale;

    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000);
}

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    return _contentView;
}

- (IBAction)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    if (_scrollView.zoomScale < _scrollView.maximumZoomScale)
        [_scrollView setZoomScale:_scrollView.maximumZoomScale animated:YES];
    else
        [_scrollView setZoomScale:_scrollView.minimumZoomScale animated:YES];
}
```

**UPDATE:** I've tried using Reveal app (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS7E4.png)), but couldn't find anything useful for me:

[image: Reveal app]

Comment: Why do you use a contentview and do not add the imageview directly to the scrollview?

Comment: Because this is a simplified test case prepared by me for StackOverflow. In the real app there will be more stuff on the `contentView` - labels and draggable letter tiles: https://raw.github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/master/DragScroll/screenshot.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My source code seems to be okay, but in Interface Builder I had to disable "Autoresize Subviews" for the `scrollView`:

[image: Xcode screenshot]